# Column header not displaying when using facet. Any suggestions please

Tags: visualforce, checkbox

I am having a check box to select/deselect the accounts. I have the used the following script. But did not get the column header which is "`Subscribe (Yes/No)`". Any thoughts please. Thanks.

```
<apex:column headerValue="Subscribe (Yes/No)">
     <apex:outputText />
     <apex:facet name="header">
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!allChecked}">
           <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!CheckAll}" rerender="AccountsTable"/>
         </apex:inputCheckbox>
      </apex:facet>
      <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sap.IsChecked}" />
</apex:column>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your "facet" is overriding the "columnHeader" property. You can either have the text or the checkbox, but not both, if you code it like that. If you want text and checkbox then put the text inside the "facet" tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
               <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apexoutputText value="Subscribe (Yes/No)"/>
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!allChecked}">
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!CheckAll}" rerender="AccountsTable"/>
                        </apex:inputCheckbox>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sap.IsChecked}" />
                </apex:column>
```

Should do the trick.